# can't shorten if statement into ternary

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ternary-operator

I'm trying to get more used to using ternary operators instead of if/else statements.

The first version of the code posted below works, yet the second version gives me an error message saying that their is no length property for the parameter longest, yet since I've set an initial condition of an empty string that length should be 0.

Here's both versions of my code. It'd be great if anyone could figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Working code w/ if statement

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var strSplit = str.split(' ');
  var longestWord = strSplit.reduce(function(longest, currentWord) {
    if(currentWord.length > longest.length)
       return currentWord;
    else
       return longest;
  }, "");
  return longestWord;
}

console.log(findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

Code w/ ternary statement that doesn't work

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var strSplit = str.split(' ');
  var longestWord = strSplit.reduce(function(longest, currentWord) {
    currentWord.length > longest.length ? currentWord : longest;
  }, "");
  return longestWord;
}

console.log(findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

My error message is:

currentWord.length > longest.length ? currentWord : longest;
                                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: You need to return the result of the ternary. `return condition ? A : B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var strSplit = str.split(' ');
  var longestWord = strSplit.reduce(function(longest, currentWord) {
    return currentWord.length > longest.length ? currentWord : longest;
  }, "");
  return longestWord;
}
```

return results.

If you don't return the results then it will default to return undefined. It will try to get the length of undefined and that is why it throws an error.

Comment: Answers are always better if they include some words outside the code to explain what you've done and why.

Answer (score 7):

you missed returning the result of ternary operation result

```
return currentWord.length > longest.length ? currentWord : longest;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
currentWord.length > longest.length ? currentWord : longest;
```

is not the ternary form of

```
if(currentWord.length > longest.length)
    return currentWord;
else
    return longest;
```

because you forgot to include the `return` statement:

```
return currentWord.length > longest.length ? currentWord : longest;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

function findLongestWord(str) {

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var strSplit = str.split(' ');
  return strSplit.reduce(function(longest, currentWord) {
    return (currentWord.length > longest.length) ? currentWord : longest;
  });
}

document.write(findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```